# Is there a way to set the default values of Preferences, like e.g. in Android?

Tags: codenameone

I want to initialize the `Preferences` default values for my mobile application. Is there a standard way to do it or should I do it in my own way?

I used the `init()` method to do so, but I would like to know if there is any built-in way to do it.

Comment: Setting your default values `Preferences.set("defaultValuet",true);`  in `init()` sounds like a right idea. All these Preferences will be stored unless you manually delete/rewrite them, or user erase all data stored in the app.

Comment: About the fnklstn comment, Preferences could be not deleted on Android if you remove the app. It depends by the brand and model of the Android device. To force Android to remove them on app uninstalling, you must use the build hint android.allowBackup=false

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani you mean even when I use the `init()` method approach?
It may make sense to ensure `Preferences` are not backed up, but where am I supposed to set the command?
Depending on the answer, it may worth investigating setting the command from within the app dynamically, so as I do not have to make this choice for the user.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani is right, I forgot about `android.allowBackup=false`

Comment: @Spyros If you want Preferences to be always stored, you just set them and they will be stored even, as Francesco mentioned, if the app was removed. 
If you want Preferences to be deleted with the app, you add `codename1.arg.android.allowBackup=false` in your `codenameone_settings.properties`.
You can set `Preferences.set("defaultValue",true);` anywhere later in your app, not just in `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the problem?

Codename One has two ways of defining the defaults for get:

```
String value = Preferences.get("MyKey", "DefaultValue");
```

or:

```
String otherValue = Preferences.getAndSet("MyKey", "DefaultValue");
```

The latter is used the default value is set into the field so you don't need to keep using default values in the code.

Comment: Yes, I later realized that there is this default value, however, I would appreciate a `Preferences.get()` method with out a `default` argument and handle any potential `Exception` myself.
I find very useful the method you suggest. There are a couple of cases that I would also just want to retrieve the value without having it changed to a `default` despite user's consent.
For the moment, I stick with the `init()` approach to initialize the `Preferences` on first launch.

Comment: The behavior without the default is problematic. Some would expect null, others would expect an exception. You can just do a class called MyPreferences with a static method that will invoke: `String val = Preferences.get(key, null); if(val == null) throw new RuntimeException("Missing key: " + key); return val;`

Comment: Yes, you are right about the assumptions and the problematic of a non-default value approach. I made the initial comment, taking into account that `Exception`s are properly handled already.
Perhaps, reconsider providing as a built-in available option with a strong warning about handling the potentially related `Exception`s?
In any case, a custom `Class` works as well.

In the mean time, I have implemented this without a custom `Class`, leveraging a validation mechanism which does not allow the default value to persist.